# AFL qemu mode not working with dlopen()

Tags: qemu, fuzzing

everyone. 
I am using AFL with qemu mode. And I've wrote this small binary to test everything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    typedef int (*pf_t)(char*);
    void* handle;
    char* error;
    char mystring[100];

    fgets(mystring,sizeof(mystring),stdin);
    printf("mystring: %s\n",mystring);

    handle = dlopen("libdiag.so",RTLD_NOW);
    if(!handle){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",dlerror());
    exit(1);
    }


    dlclose(handle);

    return 0;
```

}

Everything works well if I don't add dlopen(). But if I add it, afl will stop  here.
The command I am using is "afl-fuzz -i in -o out -Q ./a.out"

```
afl-fuzz 2.49b by <lcamtuf@google.com>
[+] You have 8 CPU cores and 3 runnable tasks (utilization: 38%).
[+] Try parallel jobs - see docs/parallel_fuzzing.txt.
[*] Checking CPU core loadout...
[+] Found a free CPU core, binding to #1.
[*] Checking CPU scaling governor...
[*] Setting up output directories...
[+] Output directory exists but deemed OK to reuse.
[*] Deleting old session data...
[+] Output dir cleanup successful.
[*] Scanning 'in'...
[+] No auto-generated dictionary tokens to reuse.
[*] Creating hard links for all input files...
[*] Validating target binary...
[*] Attempting dry run with 'id:000000,orig:aahat.jpg'...
[*] Spinning up the fork server...
[+] All right - fork server is up.
```

I don't know why. All I know is that someone said afl qemu mode has something wrong with dlopen. I am wondering someone can give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: any news on this? I'm also stuck here

Comment: Not really. I still don't know how to do this.

Comment: I found out how to get rid of that, use `LD_PRELOAD=path_to_your_lib afl-fuzz ...`

Comment: are you researching into software bug hunting? mind adding me as friend to share experience?

Comment: I mean adding friend on some social network, wechat probably? what's your id?

Comment: Hi, I put my wechat number here for two days.. If you still want to add friend just email me at xudong_shao@hotmail.com with your id. I don't want to put my id here for too long ...